# Sometimes shortcut keys stop working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xfce

Since I started using the xfce desktop enviroment, there are time when keyboard shortcuts stop working and the only way to make them work again is by restarting my laptop.

Anyone know about this problem and if it is a fixable problem? I have searched around for the solution for this problem but have not found anything that has helped me.

Thanks in advance!